# How to refactor php href links to respond with Modal or popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am rewriting some text which is heavy with footnotes in the form

```
<a id="par170_fn1" href="get_footnote.php?id=118">[1]</a>
```

The footnotes are organized in a table.

I'm a little confused by the technical flow of executing these refactorings using modal dialog or popovers. It seems that Ajax is inherently part of the process.

I'm a little stuck on the concept of matching the dynamic data where.

This example from the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#tooltips-and-popovers) makes sense in general, but I'm missing the bridge that allows my retrieved data to be accounted for in the call.
Plus I don't want to replace the links with buttons.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <h5>Popover in a modal</h5>
  <p>This <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-test" title="Popover title" data-content="Popover body content is set in this attribute.">button</a> triggers a popover on click.</p>
  <hr>
  <h5>Tooltips in a modal</h5>
  <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">that link</a> have tooltips on hover.</p>
</div>
```

I would appreciate some tips on how to think this through on a fundamental level.

Comment: To clarify, you have various footnote links, which when clicked you would like to load the footnote details from a remote PHP script, and display them in a Bootstrap modal? What format is the data returned from the PHP script? JSON, HTML, or something else?

Comment: Depending on the length of the footnote reference, you might simply be able to follow [this Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content).

Comment: Yes. fubar. The data is in HTML format. Though returning JSON may be a later refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to resolve the problem I had to go back and examine some foundational logic.

1. I created my html in php using echo statements. It was how I originally wrote it, when I was learning about PHP. Time for a refactor. Used html, embedding the small amount of PHP as needed with code tags.
2. I was using an older version of bootstrap which allowed a functionality which is deprecated in BS4. I didn't realize that functionality was in effect until the previously working code was failing with BS4.
3. Using the latest BS made me aware of the need for jQuery AJAX. I wanted to stay in vamilla JS, but I realized I understand JS much better than I thought and was then able to use the jQuery docs to get a handle on the remote data being pulled from a PHP GET.
4. I refactored my php script to return JSON and do the data wrangling on the server end and simply pass the desired data to my js script for populating the modal.
5. I set up the modal divs, which is actually far simpler than I was complaining about.
6. I refactored the footnote tags in the database. A simple task using replace functionality in my database tool.

So here's how I resolved my issue:

1. Refactor the tags to this format:

```html
<sup><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#footnote-modal" id="par180_fn10" href="footnote.php?id=127">[10]</a></sup>
```

2. Format the modal html:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="footnote-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
   <!-- Modal header -->
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="footnoteTitle"></h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
   </div>
   <!-- Modal Body -->
   <div class="modal-body" id="footnote_detail"></div>
      <!-- Modal Footer -->
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

3. Enable the JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#footnote-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(dataString){
  //console.dir(dataString.relatedTarget);
  var location = dataString.relatedTarget.attributes[3].value;
  console.log(location);
  $.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: location,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(res){
    //console.dir(res);
          $('#footnoteTitle').html(res.data[0] + res.data[1] + 
           res.data[2] + res.data[3] + ", Footnote " + res.footnote_no);
          $('#footnote_detail').html(res.footnote_text);
   }
  })
  .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
      alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
      console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
      console.log( "Status: " + status );
      console.dir( xhr );
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create hyperlinks for each footnote as follows:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit <sub><a class="footnote" href="/footnote.php?id=123">[123]</a></sub>.</p>
```

Then you can bind a click event using jQuery to fetch the HTML content using AJAX, inject it into a Bootstrap modal and launch the modal.

```
$('.footnote').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $modal = $('#footnote-modal');

    $.get(event.target.href, function (response) {
        $modal.find('.modal-body').html(response);
        $modal.modal();
    });
});
```

Here's an example, where I've substitued an AJAX call using `$.get` with a `Promise` to illustrate how the code would work.

```js
// For example purposes only
var html = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas architecto voluptatem, natus temporibus quasi labore repellat laboriosam culpa.</p>';

$('.footnote').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $modal = $('#footnote-modal');
  
  // For example purposes only
  Promise.resolve(html)
    .then(function (response) {
       $modal.find('.modal-body').html(response);
       $modal.modal();
    });
  
  // Actual code to call your PHP script
  // $.get(event.target.href, function (response) {
  //   $modal.find('.modal-body').html(response);
  //   $modal.modal();
  // });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit <sub><a class="footnote" href="/footnote.php?id=123">[123]</a></sub>.</p>
  <p>Dolorum ducimus quos officia blanditiis expedita <sub><a class="footnote" href="/footnote.php?id=123">[456]</a></sub>.</p>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="footnote-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Footnote</h3>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any questions, just ask.

Comment: Gahhhhh!! The comment ui is really crappy for engaging in conversation around questions answers. I'm going to see if I can get this working. I definitely have some questions, But first let me try and implement what you've presented.

Comment: Do I replace the $.get with AJAX? I'd like to do the AJAX call with vanilla JS, will that work in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you want to use vanilla JS, when Bootstrap already requires jQuery?

Comment: And FYI, `$.get` is simply a jQuery wrapper for an `xhr` call.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense. Just bear with it. I don't want to explain my reasoning right now.

Comment: I'm still having the page redirect from the href="get_footnote.php?id=xxx".
The modal is not activating. What I would really like is a popover. But if understanding how to execute the modal helps, I can figure it out.

Comment: The code I posted works. Have you copied it all? Including the `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176826/discussion-between-ken-ingram-and-fubar).